# Return a value from onResponse Android

Tags: java, android, android-volley

Instead of \"return true" how can i return value of "complited1" or "strIsCompleted" as boolean ?

"Don`t read this", thanks :p
There are many variations of passages of available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected , words which don't look even slightly believable. If you are going to use a passage of , you need to be sure there isn't anything embarrassing hidden in the middle of text.

```
    public boolean GetStatusByCategoryID(final String categoryID) {




    final StringRequest req = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, " http://164.132.6.62/api/Answer/CheckCompleteness?userid=9",
        new Response.Listener < String > () {


            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                try {


                    VolleyLog.v("Response:%n %s", response);
                    Toast.makeText(HomeView.this, response.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                    JSONArray jsonMainArray = new JSONArray(response);

                    //check length of json array
                    if (jsonMainArray.length() > 0) {
                        for (int i = 0; i < jsonMainArray.length(); i++) {



                            JSONObject jsonObject = jsonMainArray.getJSONObject(i);
                            String strCategoryId = jsonObject.isNull("categoryId") ? "" : jsonObject.optString("categoryId");
                            String strIsCompleted = jsonObject.isNull("isCompleted") ? "" : jsonObject.optString("isCompleted").toString();
                            if (strCategoryId.equals(categoryID)) {
                                String complited1 = strIsCompleted;


                                System.out.println(complited1);

                            }




                        }

                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                VolleyLog.e("Error: ", error.getMessage());
                Toast.makeText(HomeView.this, "Server error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }) {
        @Override
        public Map < String, String > getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            HashMap < String, String > headers = new HashMap < String, String > ();
            headers.put("Authorization", "bWVuZGltbXVzdGFmYTpMb3RyMyNMb2d5");
            return headers;
        }
    };



    //Add Network Request in request queue
    RequestQueue mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
    req.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
        DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_MS * 20000,
        DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
        DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
    mRequestQueue.add(req);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: First: when you say you want to return a string as a boolean, what do you mean? What logic are you planning to use to decide which strings correspond to true and which to false? 

Secondly, I have no idea what your second paragraph means -- needs edits for legibility at the very last.

Comment: It means *I was prompted to insert more text due to my question containing too much code compared to the size of its textual part*, most likely...

Answer (score 0):

Im not entirely sure what you mean, but with a method we can change what it returns by changing its variable type.

E.g.

```
public void method1(){
//Returns nothing/ is voided
}

public string method2(){
String returnString = "hello";

return returnString;
}
```

method 2 when called would get a string, when printed would say "hello".

Answer (score 0):

As I understood, you want to change the boolean in onResponse. So you must do like this.

```
interface CustomCallback {
   void onResponse(boolean parameter);
}
```

And pass the interface as parameter to your method, like this

```
public boolean GetStatusByCategoryID(final String categoryID, CustomCallback callback)
```

Then just call it in your onResponse or onError

```
callback.onResponse(/*true or false*/);
```

Comment: i need to get "complited1"( is a string) if the string is true as text return true(boolean) if the complited1 is false as text return false

Comment: Yeah as I told you. if "compiled1" is true u just need to callback.onResponse(true);. Cause you are doing asynchronous call and you can't directly return a value.